# Isomorphisma problem in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field $f \in F[x]$ and $\deg(f)=m,m\in \mathbb{N^+}$ is a monic polynomial and $$\frac{F[x]}{\langle\,f\,\rangle}=\{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+....a_{m-1}t^{m-1}:a_i\in F, f(t)=0\}$$
Then $R=\frac{F[x]}{\langle\,x^3\,\rangle}$ can we find an isomorphism $S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
a&b&c\\
0&a&b\\
0&0&a\\
\end{pmatrix}
:a,b,c \in F\right\}
$ between R and S. $R'=\frac{F[x]}{\langle\,x^2-x\,\rangle}$ isomorphic with $F×F$

Comment: What is your question?  And I don't think that your definition of $F[x]/\langle f\rangle$ makes sense.  At least, your definition means $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^3\rangle = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi, you appear to have confused the title field for the tags field. Also, since your post is just a problem statement, it's likely to be rapidly closed. Perhaps you should start making edits now so you can save/revive it.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the normal definition of the quotient.

Write an element of $R$ as $a + bx + cx^2$, then map this element to
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a&b&c\\
0&a&b\\
0&0&a\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
this is clearly a bijection between $R$ and $S$. It remains to show that it is a homomorphism of rings. One does this by simply working with the explicit addition and multiplication in the rings (i.e., first checking the map respects addition and subtraction and then writing out $(a + bx + cx^2)(a' + b'x + c'x^2)$ and checking that this maps to the correct element of $S$ noting that $x^3 = 0$ in $R$). I will leave this to you.

For the second question this is a special case of the chinese remainder theorem. Factor $x^2 - x = x(x - 1)$ and with this in mind consider the map
$$F[x] \to F \times F$$
taking $x$ to $(0, 1)$. Notice that this is enough to define a homomorphism since every element of $F[x]$ may be written as a sum $a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$, and we require that $1 \mapsto 1$.

it is not hard to check that this is a surjective homomorphism. By the factorisation of the polynomial above the kernel of this map is precisely $\langle x^2 -x \rangle$.

Comment: How can I show surjective homeomrofism